# VS2010 gives errors when programming in qt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I've got a question regarding the use of Qt with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I've installed Visual Studio, Qt and the Qt VS2010 plugin. Everything works fine, and I can compile simple programs. Only one thing that doesn't work like it should.

When I am writing code in the VS2010 editor, I get errors like "Error: identifier QApplication is undefined." or "Error: cannot open source file QApplication". The code that I am using is

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    test w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I think it has something to do with linking the code checker to the source files of Qt but I can't find this option somewhere in VS2010.

Regards,

Comment: I don't know too much about VS, but, does your project itself have the include paths added? Sounds like the build configuration knows to include it, but not the actual project